# Is it possible to make a polar (radial) filled.contour map? Geopotential in Antarctica data

Tags: r, plot

I am working with reanalysis data (ERA 5) of 500 hPa Geopotential to analyze Southern Annular Mode patterns in the Antarctic region for the period 1998-2016, specifically the dimensions LON [0, 360°] and LAT [-50, -90°] with a resolution of 0.25°x0.25°. I have a monthly mean data series, so the total dimensions of my original array is: 1440 (LON), 161 (LAT), 228 (time).

Here is the link to my data:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/100VkPCH3RthSumqyHKc-w_6-2fPg8XNV?usp=sharing

I have managed to plot the data with filled.contour (my target map), but with straight axes, as I show below.

```
#charge the data
datos_geo <- nc_open("geopotential_antartida.nc")
geo <- ncvar_get(datos_geo, "z")
lon <- ncvar_get(datos_geo, "longitude")
lat <- ncvar_get(datos_geo, "latitude")
py <- c(length(lat):1)
lat <- lat[py]

#make the map
media_geo <- apply(geo, c(1,2), mean)
paleta2 <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "palegreen", "yellow", "red"),interpolate='linear')
par(mar=c(3,3,3,3), mfrow=c(2,1), cex.axis=0.5, cex.lab=0.5, cex.main=0.9, mgp=c(1.5,0.5,0))
filled.contour(lon, lat, media_geo, color.palette=paleta2,
               plot.title=title(main="", xlab="Longitud [°]", ylab="Latitud [°]"),
               plot.axes={axis(1); axis(2); map("antarctica", wrap=c(-180,180), 
                                                add=T, fill=TRUE,border=F, col = "white")})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnGxB.png)

My goal is to make a filled.contour map (or similar) but radial, and with the Antarctic continent underneath. I have managed to make a radial map, but only with the continent, without plotting my data on top.

Is it possible to plot both together? Thanks in advance.

```
install.packages(c("ggOceanMapsData", "ggOceanMaps"), 
                 repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org",
                           "https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/drat"))
library(ggOceanMapsData)
library(ggOceanMaps)
basemap(limits = -50, glaciers = TRUE, bathymetry = F)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9fS9.png)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/AustralianAntarcticDivision/SOmap

Comment: Thank you Sarah. I looked at that package before making the post. I managed to add spatial points to the map, but I couldn't find a way to plot a data matrix above the map. I just edited my post and added a link to a Drive folder with my data.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry I've never actually used SOmap, I just knew it existed so thought it might help

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a lot of time trying to make a radial (polar) map to plot the 500 hPa Geopotential data for Antarctica.

I finally discovered that I can accomplish this with the wonderful function I didn't know about, `PlotStereoMap`, from the `s2dverification` package. Here my code and map:

```
PlotStereoMap(verano2008_med, lon, lat, latlims = c(-30,-90), toptitle = "SAM (+)", 
              title_scale = 0.7, bar_limits = range(verano2008_med),
              triangle_ends = c(T,T), units = "m2/s2", units_scale = 0.7,
              bar_label_scale = 0.7, bar_tick_scale = 0.4)
```

[image]

However, I am now struggling with changing the plot parameters. I've read them all and tried everything, but I can't get the color scale to be smaller (it's almost the size of the map!) and I'd also like it to be horizontal at the bottom of the map.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30926510)

Comment: I managed to create a smaller color scale creating it separately. After exporting them separately I joined them in Canvas. Here is the code I used: 

ColorBar(vertical = F, subsampleg = 2,
         bar_limits = range(verano2008_med),
         color_fun = clim.palette(palette = "bluered"),
         plot = T, draw_ticks = T, draw_separators = F,
         title = "m2/s2", title_scale = 0.6,
         label_scale = 0.8, label_digits = 3, tick_scale = 0.4,
         extra_margin = c(6,1,6,1))
However, I still cannot plot the longitude values around the map with the PlotStereoMap() function.